# apache отдает php как текст

Tags: php, apache, openserver

Скопировал сайт с хостинга на локальный сервер openServer и столкнулся с проблемой, что сервер при ajax запросе к файлу, отдает его текст как есть. Т.е. не обрабатывает его, хотя на хостинге все было нормально. Да и на других локальных сайтах на openServer все обрабатывает хорошо.
Подскажите где искать проблему? В настройке этих вещей не силен.

Comment: А если не ajax? php подключен как модуль или cgi?

Comment: @tutankhamun сайт работает, страницы генерятся... как бы с этим нормально все.... А вот как подключен я сказать не могу... в настройке серверов я дуб :) Просто поставил openserver и пользуюсь... а что там и где хз

Comment: Если этот файл вызвать не через AJAX, а просто через адресную строку, результат такой же?

Comment: @tutankhamun да такой же. Я решил проблему. Там в одном из катологов по иерархии выше был htaccess с `RemoveType`, где в числе расширений так же был и php.

Comment: @pepel_xD можете ответ написать сами и пометить его как правильный.

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего у вас в php файле открывающий тег `<?`, а должно быть `<?php`

Comment: Да нет, нормально все, есть и окрывающий `<?php` и закрывающий `?>`

Comment: Почему вы решили, что так должно быть? short_open_tag пока никто не отменял. Да, это плохая практика, но количество кода в Интернете с таким тегом просто чудовищное